# SQL - Issue with WHERE logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 columns, lets call them `column A`, `column B` and `column C` each column is a date.

I am trying to write the where logic like this:

If column A is NULL or if column C date is greater than today's today minus 3 days
If column B is NULL or if column C date is greater than today's today minus 3 days
If column C is NULL or if column C date is greater than today's today minus 3 days

I have came up with this, but when I run it, I am missing items:

```
( columnA IS NULL OR columnA >= Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate()) ) 
AND
( columnB IS NULL OR columnB >= Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate()) ) 
AND
( columnC IS NULL OR columnC >= Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate()) )
```

This is causing a conflict, for an example, I have one item that is missing and here is why:

columnA date is less then today's date minus 3 days
columnB date is less then today's date minus 3 days
columnC is NULL

therefore since columnC is NULL, the item should appear. What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: This is a catch-all query. They are a bit challenging and performance can be absolutely awful. Take a look at this article which explains a number of ways of dealing with this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: @user979331 you have used "AND" condition which will fetch data only if all 3 conditions are satisfied, the missing data you mentions doesn't satisfy the 1st 2 conditions hence doesn't appear in output. Use a "OR" condition and see if it works.

Comment: Post some sample data that should meet your criteria but isn't.

Comment: Your written-out conditions say "column C date is greater..." for all three cases, but your SQL has `columnA >=`, `columnB >=`. Is one of them incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem-description, and your code, differ in the association of the 'greater'-clause, so the answer is not unambiguously, either. Please precise your question in case - also see the hints for optimization by the former comment.

a) This should be the logically correct answer to your description:

```
WHERE ( columnA IS NULL OR columnB IS NULL OR columnC IS NULL OR columnC >= Getdate()-3 )
```

b) Derived from your code, this should be the logically correct answer (but not optimized yet) :

```
WHERE (   columnA IS NULL OR columnA >= Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate())  
       OR columnB IS NULL OR columnB >= Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate())
       OR columnC IS NULL OR columnC >= Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate()) 
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you really want to use `OR` rather than `AND` between your clauses.

```
( columnA IS NULL OR columnA >= Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate()) ) 
OR
( columnB IS NULL OR columnB >= Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate()) ) 
OR
( columnC IS NULL OR columnC >= Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate()) )
```

Comment: This returns items that should not be there :(

Comment: Please post some sample data then.

Answer (score 0):

If column A is NULL or if column C date is greater than today's today minus 3 days If column B is NULL or if column C date is greater than today's today minus 3 days If column C is NULL or if column C date is greater than today's today minus 3 days

```
( columnA IS NULL 
                  OR columnC >= 
                     Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate()) ) 
           AND ( columnB IS NULL 
                  OR columnC >= 
                     Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate()) ) 
           AND ( columnC IS NULL 
                  OR columnC >= 
                     Dateadd(day, -3, Getdate()) )
```

in case you want to retrieve data which satisfies all the three conditions use `AND` as you are using else if you want to retrieve data which matches any one of the condition use `OR` instead of `AND`